# scons: adding extra flags from external command line leads to compilation error

Tags: c++, file, object, scons

I've got a libxml2 test file called testlibxml2.cpp. I tried to compile it wish scons like this:

```
import os
env=Environment(ENV=os.environ)

cflags=os.popen("xml2-config --cflags").read()
lflags=os.popen("xml2-config --libs").read()
env.Program(target='testlibxml2', 
source='testlibxml2.cpp',CCFLAGS=cflags, LIBS=lflags)
```

Compilation has error because the g++ command is missing the source filename, and no linking is eventuall done:

```
g++ -o cpp/build/testlibxml2.o -c -I/usr/include/libxml2

clang: error: no input files
```

Then I tried to fix it using an Object file as intermediate step:

```
cflags=os.popen("xml2-config --cflags").read()
lflags=os.popen("xml2-config --libs").read()
env.Append(CCFLAGS=cflags)
obj=Object('testlibxml2.cpp',CCFLAGS=cflags)
env.Program(target='testlibxml2', source=obj,CCFLAGS=cflags, LIBS=lflags)
```

Still it fails with error:

```
g++ -o cpp/build/testlibxml2.o -c -I/usr/include/libxml2
```

clang: error: no input files

Why the behavior of scons is so weird:

> It fail to populate the source file name when using external command output
>
> It fail to provide a link step after that.

How to fix it?

---

Thanks, got 2 kinds of fixes:

```
cflags=os.popen("xml2-config --cflags").read()
lflags=os.popen("xml2-config --exec-prefix=/usr --libs").read()
env.Append(CCFLAGS=cflags)
env.Append(LINKFLAGS=lflags)
```

Another is:

```
env.ParseConfig("xml2-config --cflags --exec-prefix=/usr --libs")
```

Comment: Why does the command line show the path `cpp/build/testlibxml2.o` when you only specify `testlibxml2.cpp` in the SConstruct? Are you using variant dirs? If yes, please say so and present the full build setup (MWE), such that other people can reproduce the problem.

Comment: You also may want to have a look at the [UserGuide](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html) and search for the description of the `ParseConfig` method...

Comment: Yes, I'm using variant dir which is specified as "cpp/build". Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `g++` for compiling and `clang` for linking?

Comment: shouldn't source be a list?